# spring-rest-data) Is the HandleBefore* annotation deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a question about spring data rest.

I want to use HandleBefore, After* annotations.
ex) @HandleBeforeCreate... etc

If you look for the document

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events.application-listener

Like the link above, it even provides a guide to using annotations as a sample.

on the other hand

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html

according this link it's on the deprecated list, so I'm confused.

help me!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is the field `HandleBeforeCreate.value` being deprecated, not the annotation `HandleBeforeCreate`.